# lift a tkMessageBox

Tags: python, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I am using tkMessageBox.showinfo ([info at tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_messagebox.htm)) to popup warnings in my program.

The problem happens only when the warning is called with a second TopLevel window (apart from the main one) on screen: in this case the warning remains hidden behind the second TL window.

I tried to call it thus:

```
tkMessageBox.showinfo(title='Warning',message=s).lift()
```

but it doesnt work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the message box is only ever guaranteed to be above its parent. If you create a second toplevel and you want a messagebox to be on top of that second window, make that second window the parent of the messagebox.

```
tl2 = tk.Toplevel(...)
...
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Say Hello", "Hello World", parent=tl2)
```

Comment: In my case `parent=...`, solved in my case that the TopLevel Window closed/terminated/(hide?) *for no reason*. Which was also an ignoring problem. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the issue that you describe. The code I wrote below is just about the minimum needed to create a window which creates a second window. The second window creates an info box using the `showinfo` method. I wonder whether you have something besides this. (Note that I made the windows somewhat large in order to attempt cover up the info window.)

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button, Toplevel
import tkMessageBox

top = Tk()
def make_window():
    t = Toplevel(top)
    t.title("I'm Window 2. Look at me too!")
    B2 = Button(t, text = "Click me", command = hello)
    B2.pack()
    t.geometry('500x500+50+50')

def hello():
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Say Hello", "Hello World")

B1 = Button(top, text = "New Window", command = make_window)
B1.pack()

top.title("I'm Window 1. Look at me!")
top.geometry('500x500+100+100')
top.mainloop()
```

This was tested on Windows 7 (64-bit) using Python 2.7 (32-bit). It produces something like this:

[image]